# Grade distribution code need help editting

Tags: java

My code is not providing the output I would like.

**Code**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GradeDistribution 
{
    private static int a, b, c, d, f;
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("        Get Grade Counts");
        System.out.print("\nEnter number of letter grade A: ");
        a = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter number of letter grade B: ");
        b = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter number of letter grade C: ");
        c = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter number of letter grade D: ");
        d = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter number of letter grade F: ");
        f = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("0   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100%");
        System.out.println("|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |");
        System.out.println("**************************************************");
        int totalGrades = a+b+c+d+f;
        int Acent = (a*100/totalGrades);
        int Bcent = (b*100/totalGrades);
        int Ccent = (c*100/totalGrades);
        int Dcent = (d*100/totalGrades);
        int Fcent = (f*100/totalGrades);
        while(((Acent)/2)-1>0)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
            Acent--;
        }
        System.out.print(" A");
        System.out.println();
        while(((Bcent)/2)-1>0)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
            Bcent--;
        }
        System.out.print(" B");
        System.out.println();
        while(((Ccent)/2)-1>0)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
            Ccent--;
        }
        System.out.print(" C");

        System.out.println();
        while(((Dcent)/2)-1>0)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
            Dcent--;
        }
        System.out.print(" D");
        System.out.println();
        while(((Fcent)/2)-1>0)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
            Fcent--;
        }
        System.out.print(" F");
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
        Get Grade Counts

Enter number of letter grade A: 1
Enter number of letter grade B: 4
Enter number of letter grade C: 6
Enter number of letter grade D: 2
Enter number of letter grade F: 1

0   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100%
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
**************************************************
**** A
************************* B
*************************************** C
*********** D
**** F
```

**Desired Output**

```
        Get Grade Counts

Enter number of letter grade A: 1
Enter number of letter grade B: 4
Enter number of letter grade C: 6
Enter number of letter grade D: 2
Enter number of letter grade F: 1

0   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100%
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
**************************************************
**** A
*************** B
********************** C
******* D
**** F
```

Comment: please clarify your question.

Comment: I've had a go at editing to the layout to what I think you intended. However its still difficult to understand which bit of the code you are not happy with, is it the number of stars shown before each letter? Please could you add some more details specifically describing the problem - then you will get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem you are having is in the logic you are using to print out the number of * for each letter.  If you work through your logic for say C, you would expect it to print about 21* to coincide with the roughly 42% that C represents from the total amount.  However your logic is causing the while loop to run too many times.  the (Ccent/2)-1 even with you decrementing Ccent in each iteration through the loop is still repeating numbers and not reducing by one each time.

A much better way to do this logic is to do it in a for loop

```
    //this loop says that for int i, exicute the block of code
    //and then increment i once for each pass through the loop
    //and do this for as long as i is <= Acent/2
    for(int i = 1;i<=Acent/2;i++){

          System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println(" A");// this formats the letter at end of *
```

This is the example for your Acent, I will leave you to practice and work through setting up the other ones.  This is a much better approach because you are iterating to a fixed number (Acent/2) and it is set to increment by one on each pass.  I believe this outputs *** for A and F due to rounding, so you may have to tinker with how this outputs or adjust your marker to help display when your percent is between two even numbers.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I figured out that I needed to take the "divided by 2" out of the loop and into the Acent.

Answer (score 0):

The output seems to be okay. This is what I get when I ran it on eclipse sdk:

```
    Get Grade Counts

Enter number of letter grade A: 6
Enter number of letter grade B: 4
Enter number of letter grade C: 7
Enter number of letter grade D: 2
Enter number of letter grade F: 1

0   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100%
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
**************************************************
*************************** A
***************** B
******************************** C
******* D
** F
```

Describe your problem further if not yet solved.
Although, I think the font you are using may be the problem. Try a different font and see what happens.